# Limit of an integral of a polynomial

Tags: integration

I don't know how I should evaluate the following limit:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) =  \lim_{x \rightarrow c} \int^c_x 2u \,du$$

Comment: What do you THINK the answer is? (even if you have no idea how to prove it)

Comment: The lower limit of the integral and the differential use the same notation ($x$). This is not good. You'd better change it to $\int_x^c 2udu$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to c}\int_{x}^c 2udu=\lim_{x\to c}(c^2-x^2)=0$$

Comment: As user1551 pointed out above, it's very important that you not use the same variable for limits of integration as the dummy variable of integration.